# Can reincarnation be proved using a mixture of scientific reasoning and philosophical belief?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, theology, philosophy-of-religion, buddhism, reason

**Let's go through the logic first. The following statements are suppositions that must be chronologically accepted.**

1. Matter is neither created nor destroyed.
2. Matter is made up of atoms.
3. I am made up of atoms.
4. I am matter.
5. Therefore, I cannot be created nor destroyed.

**Now here's the philosophical (or perhaps, ideological) part:**

With respect to statements 3-5 above, what defines "I"? Am (or Is) "I" the atoms that compose my form or am (or is) "I" the identity that I have created for myself?

If "I" am my atoms, then when "I" die, I will continue to exist because my atoms will, albeit in a different form - a different incarnation hence, reincarnation. If "I" am my identity, then when "I" die, I will cease to exist.

I think the former highlights a type of belief common in eastern philosophy (we are the universe) whereas the latter is common is western philosophy (We live in the universe, or we observe the universe).

Perhaps one's identity is linked with their atomic structure (i.e., the chemical processes of the brain)?

Do you think my reasoning is sound?

Edit: to make it clear, I am supporting the idea that if one believes that "I" is based on the existence of atoms, then reincarnation is in fact real.

Comment: In my opinion a person is not the sum of her/his atoms. To capture the personality, one has to add at least the dynamics due to the physiological and mental processes. The personality dissolves at death even when the atoms continue to exist. Hence your reasoning does not convince me.

Comment: Your reasoning does not convince me, but it's valid and sound assuming we accept the premise "I am nothing more than my atoms", to use your terms.

Comment: I think you need to define reincarnation.  You seem to be using it in an unusual way.  Do you mean that any time one of "your" atoms becomes a component of another lifeform "you" have been reborn?  If so, it's possible that "you" are presently alive in many different bodies.  It's possible that "you" and "I" are sharing a body right now.  This might be an interesting way of thinking about life, but it's not what most people would call *reincarnation*.

Comment: Premise 1 and 2 are arguably false although too vague to be sure (atoms can be split and loose mass). Conclusion 5 does not follow from 1 to 4.

Comment: @armand Well it doesn't matter than atoms can be split up. I'm not saying that atoms are the smallest unit of measuring matter. I'm saying that "matter" is stuff - atoms can be broken down and any constituent part of an atom must also be considered "matter".  In other words, if atoms are made up of protons, electrons, and neutrons, so am I, because I am made of atoms. You can distill this down to the neutrino. SO with this understanding, I cannot see how 1 and 2 can be false - maybe I'm missing something.  (1/2)

Comment: @armand As for your statement about Premise 5 ("Conclusion 5"), can you explain how it cannot come from statements 1-4? Matter cannot be created nor destroyed (law of conservation of matter), I am matter, therefore - I cannot be destroyed. If I could be destroyed, then surely I wouldn't be matter. If I wasn't matter then I wouldn't have mass and if I was massless, then I wouldn't have weight. I do have weight, therefore I have mass and thus, I must be matter. (2/2)

Comment: @Juhasz Yes this is exactly what I mean.  It's reincarnation in the literal sense.

Comment: @JoWehler Well let me ask you this: let's assume your mother lost her memory. Her physical appearance did not change but her identity did. Would you still refer to that woman as your mother? Would you say, "This lady doesn't remember who she is" or "My mother doesn't remember who she is"?

Comment: I think if we use atoms as parameter of reincarnation then in first place we never were born and never died so  reincarnation will not also take place

Comment: And are you sure memory is atom not arrangement of atom? anyways memory are argument is sort of sand dune problem.

Comment: @Ha'Penny Good point about never having been born. Assuming my premise, we always technically existed and will never not exist. Excellent point. I didn't think about it like that.

Comment: @ProfessorFinesse 1 I don't really get why you mention atoms at all, then, if it does not matter... The point being, matter can be destroyed by nuclear fission, so your premise is false. 2 if I take all your atoms and rearrange them in a big soup, it won't be you in any acceptable sense. You are more than your atoms just like a poem is more than the paper and ink it's written with, and the same ink could be used to write a recipe, that is not the poem. Even if your atoms could not be destroyed it does not follow that you can't. ("Your" atoms does not even make sense. It changes all the time.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atoms can indeed be broken apart and reassembled in a wide variety of ways, in particle accelerators. But of primary importance for objects like human beings is the fact that *molecules* can and are routinely broken apart and rearranged in everyday life. That molecular rearrangement process is how you digest food, and how your body rots after you die.

Human immortality hence requires at a minimum that *molecules* be immortal, which they are decidedly not.

Comment: Wow. minus one point for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested at in the comments, 1 is false, since the elementary particles which matter comprises can, in fact, be created and destroyed. In addition, the argument leading to 5 is a [fallacy of composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition), since, even if the constituent parts which you comprise could not be created nor destroyed, that would not entail that you could not. Therefore, your reasoning is not sound.

Comment: Elementary particles of atoms - if they have mass, cannot be created nor destroyed by definition of the Law of Conservation of Matter.  I concede to your point about the argument leading to 5 being a fallacy of composition and I must thank you for leading me to the subject of emergence. However, despite that fallacy in the structure of the argument, the premise remains scientifically true. The matter that defines me cannot be created, nor can they be destroyed. What if I simplified the argument: 1) Matter cannot be created nor destroyed 2) I am matter 3) I encompass all properties of matter?

Comment: @ProfessorFinesse Having taken a class in quantum field theory, I'm not sure what you mean by "Law of Conservation of Matter," since particle number is not a conserved quantity. Matter can be created and destroyed. For example, the [β¯ decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) of an atom creates an electron. In addition, any particle (massive or massless) can annihilate with its respective antiparticle, and more massive particles can decay into less massive ones. Looking at your simplified argument, your conclusion still does not follow from the premises.